# MVC Best Practice: Where to do mapping between models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, controller, mapping

I Have an MVC Project roughly organized like this:

1. Project 1: MVC app (ViewModels, Controller, Actions, UI-stuff)
2. Project 2: Domain Model (Domain Classes, behavior, Data Access (Persitance layer, Repositories)

My question is where to do mapping and data access (how to organize the code).

By [definition](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-controller-overview-cs) (as I understand it) the controller should map the request to the right view and be as skinny as possible.

I use Automapper on the basic mapping, and I do it in the controller, but for more complex mapping I find it easier to do the mapping myself.

**I have mainly two places to put the code for this:**

1. In the controller:

This can easily get quite messy, specially if I need to get information from several repositories, create select lists and so on.

1. In the ViewModel:

This feels better, but I don't like instansiating Repositories and UnitOfWork in the model. Don't know if that belong there.

Right now I'm doing something in between:

> I let the ViewModel take the needed repositories as contructor
>   parameters, and I do the mapping there. I instansiate the
>   Repositories/UnitOfWork in the controller and pass it in. The good
>   thing is that I can use an Interface for the repositories so the
>   ViewModel doesn't need to care about implementation.

**However, in examples on the web I always see all this code in the controller so that makes me wonder - what is the right way to do it?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do it in the ViewModel, that would mean your viewmodel has to understand your other object.  That's not good.  The ViewModel should be as dumb about external dependencies as possible.

You should be doing the mapping in the controller.

Comment: OK, thanks. That was quite clear. So I fill the viewmodel with data in the controller and perform the rest of the logic in the model? i.e. creating a selectlist for viewing data with a SelectList property with just a getter, making the list from the existing data in the model?

Comment: @cfs - There are varying opinions on this.  I treat the ui model (the models folder) as strictly view models.  I have a seperate layer for business logic, which manages the domain model.  I call into the business layer and get data back, then i map that to my view model.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, that would probably help a bit since I find it hard to go the middle road here, not doing too much in the controller, not end up with a anemic Domain Model, and still there is spesific things I need for some views that is not really related to the domain either. I might have to refactor this at some point...

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of ActionFilter Attribute to carry out the Mapping Process. Please refer the Jimmy Boggard's Blog on [How to do MVC - View Model](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/). I personally feel it is clean approach and get rid of the mapping code from the controller.

Comment: I've read that, and I like it a lot, but he really goes all the way making one ViewModel for each view, and he really knows all the ins and outs on the AutoMapper. I'm not totally confident in using Automapper for every scenario, especially since the most complex cases I find myself I have better control if I do the mapping myself. But thanks for the tip.

Comment: Welcome cfs, You can also make use of your own ActionFilter Attribute called CustomMapFilter where you can inject your Mapping Logic and maintaing an another ActionFilter Attribute targeted to use AutoMapper in Parallel. Hope it helps. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I find this approach does not work in some of the more complex scenarios with more complicated models. Just an opinion, though.

Comment: @Tanizah I don't think you're wrong but it really only hides the mapping i think and makes the controllers look cleaner (it's still there), if you get enough of the CustomMapFilters that is going to be a bit messy as well unless you can reuse the code in them in some way.